# Regular expression to negate those div having class="image"

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, regex-negation

I have string in which i want to get content of only those DIV tags which does not have the class `image`.

I am using this regular expression:

```
#<\s*?div\b[^>]*class="[^image]">(.*?)</div\b[^>]*>#s
```

but it escapes all the DIV tags, not just the ones with the class `image`

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely better off with a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) instead.

In any case, here's a regex that should do what you're after:

```
<div[^>]+class="(?!(?:.+ )?image(?: .+)?")([^"]+)"
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/eekxdFdmFR

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[^image]` will find only those classes that do not contain `i` AND `m` etc. letters. Maybe [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can do the trick:

```
#<\s*?div\b[^>]class=\"(?:(?!image).)*\">(.?)*>#s
```

It will dismiss the `class="images"` etc. too, but I hope this is a good beginning. :)

PS: I don't know the last `]` is necessary or not, but it is missing from my regexp.